# How to change style of child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How can I change the style of a child component I don't have control of?

I know about `overrides` but I can't see how to use it here.

For example

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#ff0000'
  },
  inner: {
    backgroundColor: '#00ff00',
    width: '50px',
    height: '50px',
    margin: '10px 10px'
  }
})

class Child extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <div className={styles.inner}></div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

When using this element, without changing any of its own source code, how can I change its styling?

```
const desiredStylesOfChild = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#012345'
  },
  inner: {
    backgroundColor: '#abcdef',
    width: '50%',
    height: '50%',
    margin: '10% 10%'
  }
})

class Parent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Something something</h1>
      <Child />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: You pretty much answered your own question. Override it. You'll need to be more specific about the problem you ran into.

Comment: @isherwood doesn't the child compnent itself have to support overrides?

Comment: I haven't implemented them, but that's not my understanding. See https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-override-existing-react-components.

Comment: @isherwood "Each element **now** has an identifier that developers can single out" why "now"? And how can I get the identifiers of the child elements I want to redesign?